# Symfony: route without authentication

Tags: symfony

I have security.yml configured like this:

```
security: 
 <......> 

firewalls: 
    login_firewall: 
        pattern:    ^/auth/login$ 
        anonymous:  ~ 
    secured_area: 
        pattern:    ^/ 
        form_login: 
            check_path: login_check 
            login_path: login 
            always_use_default_target_path: false 
            target_path_parameter:          _target_path 
            use_referer:                    false 
        logout: 
            path:   /logout 
            target: / 
        #anonymous: ~ 
        #http_basic: 
        #    realm: "Secured Demo Area" 

access_control: 
    - { path: ^/auth/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY } 
    - { path: ^/system/doit$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY } 
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

/auth/login should be accessible without authentication - works ok
/ should be accessible only after authentication - works ok
/system/doit should also be accessible without authentication - it does not work, will be still redirected to login page. How to get /system/doit access without login ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `anonymous:  ~` to `secured_area`.

```
secured_area: 
    pattern:    ^/ 
    anonymous:  ~
```